How to locate a device just after permissions are granted
I am currently developing an Android application that requires geolocation. However, once the permissions are granted, the application does not have enough time to retrieve the device's coordinates. I have to restart the fragment to get the location. I tried implementing the 'onRequestPermissionsResult' function, but it doesn't seem to work, and worse, it seems to be deprecated.
Here is the code of my button:
currentlocalisation.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                getLocation()
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireActivity(),
                    "move your phone from left to right in a figure-height pattern",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                model.modifyCoordinatesLocation(longitude, latitude)
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.toPostel)
            }
        })

here is the code of the "getLocation" function:
fun getLocation() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            if (isLocationEnabled()) {
                var locationByNetwork: Location? = null
                var locationByGps: Location? = null
                val gpsLocationListener: LocationListener = object : LocationListener {
                    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                        locationByGps = location
                    }

                    override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}
                    override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
                    override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
                }
                val networkLocationListener: LocationListener = object : LocationListener {
                    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                        locationByNetwork = location
                    }

                    override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}
                    override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
                    override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    5000,
                    0F,
                    gpsLocationListener
                )
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    5000,
                    0F,
                    networkLocationListener
                )
                val lastKnownLocationByGps =
                    locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                lastKnownLocationByGps?.let {
                    locationByGps = lastKnownLocationByGps
                }
                val lastKnownLocationByNetwork =
                    locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
                lastKnownLocationByNetwork?.let {
                    locationByNetwork = lastKnownLocationByNetwork
                }
                if (locationByNetwork != null) {
                    latitude = locationByNetwork!!.latitude
                    longitude = locationByNetwork!!.longitude
                }
                if (locationByGps != null) {
                    //if(locationByGps!!.accuracy > locationByNetwork!!.accuracy) {
                    latitude = locationByGps!!.latitude
                    longitude = locationByGps!!.longitude
                    //}
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        } else {
            requestPermissions()
        }

and here is the code of the "onRequestPermissionsResult" function:
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == 14555) {
            if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                getLocation()
            }
        }
    }

the call to the "getLocation" function inside the "onRequestPermissionsResult" one doesn't seem to execute... I don't understand what happens.
I tried log into the "onRequestPermissionsResult" function to debug but there is no output...
My application works well after relaunching the fragment.
But i'd like to grasp the coordinates of the device just after permissions are granted.

In getLocation() you are configuring the LocationManager after the location change triggers the listener, so you are late to catch the response. Also you don't need to define separate listeners for GPS and Network if they are basically behaving the same
Try doing something like this, worked for me
private lateinit var locationListener: LocationListener
var lastLocation: Location? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    //...

    //initialize your locationManager and listener
    locationManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    locationListener = object : LocationListener {
    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        lastLocation = location
    }

    override fun onStatusChanged(s: String, i: Int, bundle: Bundle) {}

    override fun onProviderEnabled(s: String) {}

    override fun onProviderDisabled(s: String) {}
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    if (requestCode == 14555) {
        if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            getLocation()
        }
    }
}

fun getLocation() {
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                5000,
                0F,
                locationListener
            )
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                5000,
                0F,
                locationListener
            )
            lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
            if (lastLocation == null){
                lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
            }

            if (lastLocation != null) {
                latitude = lastLocation!!.latitude
                longitude = lastLocation!!.longitude
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    } else {
        requestPermissions()
    }
}


modifying the place of the listener didn't change anything... I chose to make it with a boolean, and set it to true inside "getLocation"... then, if the boolean is true, navigate to other fragment. If i need more precision, i think it's good to have the gps location.. My code works now. Thanks for your response @LeonelBraginsky
